# Can HtmlUnit connect to an FTP site?

Tags: java, exception, browser, ftp, htmlunit

I am trying to connect to **ftp://aeneas.mit.edu/pub/palladium/** , an ftp server using HtmlUnit but am getting the following exception:

```
Could not download the page at url: ftp://aeneas.mit.edu/pub/palladium/
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:909)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:172)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1486)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1403)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:305)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:390)
        at com.osapp.UrlTester.main(ConnectToUrl.java:2650)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: Scheme 'ftp' not registered.
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.java:115)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:793)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:414)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        ... 8 more
```

**NOTE:** I am using HtmlUnit 2.12 and Java 1.7

I am able to connect to this site using chrome. Since HtmlUnit mimics a browser i feel it should be able to do most of the things a modern web browser can do. Is there a way one can connect to a ftp server using HtmlUnit?

Thanks!! I appreciate your comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. Not only based on the errors you're getting:

> Could not download the page

As well as:

> org.apache.http.HttpException: Scheme 'ftp' not registered

But also based on the HTMLUnit definition itself:

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links, etc

As you can see it is strictly related to getting data using the `HTTP` protocol.

In order to download files using `FTP` then you should use an `FTP` client library.